# Accessing data-id within modal

Tags: html, jsp, modal-dialog

I'm currently creating an edit payment method use-case for a website. This is the scenario. 
1. There is an edit button for each payment method. 
2. When the user clicks on the edit button for a method, a modal will appear for the user to enter in and submit changes for a payment method. 
3. The modal will receive the payment method id in order to differentiate which payment method I have to edit.

Currently, I am basing it off of this code.
http://jsfiddle.net/4XJ54/279/

```
<input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="" />
```

As you can see when the user clicks on the button, it reveals the value of data-id.
 What I need to do is to perform `href={data-id}.htm` but I don't know how to refer to that value in this way because it is used with the input form instead.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$("button.btn-primary").on("click", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var _self = $(this);

    var myBookId = $(".open-AddBookDialog").attr('data-id',$("#bookId").val());
    var $modal=$(".open-AddBookDialog").attr('href');
    $(".open-AddBookDialog").attr('href',$("#bookId").val()+".htm");
    $($modal).modal('hide');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4XJ54/281/)

Comment: Everything works except the href part. If I wanted to specifically href my index page, this portion would be  $(".openAddBookDialog").attr('href',"index.htm");, correct?

Comment: @compsciguy. can you explain again what you want with the href on click of save changes button.

Comment: When I click on the save changes, I want to href to a page that is dynamic due to the value of bookId. For example,                                                      <a href="preferred=${bookid}.htm"> Currently, when I click on save changes, it simply closes and doesn't seem to perform the href part.

Comment: @compsciguy. in the demo fiddle, you edit the data-id and populate it to both href and data-id attributes. It is dynamic I think.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to verify that the href part works? More info about the code: it's based on Spring so when I call the href={id}.htm it should create a new modelview and therefore, refresh the page as well.